Gyroscope Calculations

Above is an illustration of a gyroscope and now according to the right hand rule, I have given the directions of torque. Since it is a spinning wheel I have replaced the Force with the centrepetal force
$$
\tau = r \times F \\ 
\tau = r \times \frac{mv^2}{r} = m \omega^2 r^2
$$
So the Resultant torque will be
$$
\tau_R = \sqrt{\tau_1 ^2 +\tau_2 ^2} = \sqrt{m_1\omega_1 ^2r_1 ^2 + m_2\omega_2 ^2 r_2 ^2}
$$
According to my calculations, and the design of the gyroscope, the resultant torque is forward. So my question is will the gyroscope itself will move forward and can I convert the resultant torque into linear force?

Torque does not, generally, cause linear acceleration. Torque is $\tau=\frac{\mathrm{d}L}{\mathrm{d}t}$ which does not relate to linear force $F=\frac{\mathrm{d}p}{\mathrm{d}t}$.

So gyroscope can cause change only angularly not linearly

But still would the gyroscope on wheels would move around? On the direction of the torque

A gyroscope wouldn't accelerate because of its angular momentum, no.

I really dont  know
